# Oauth 2- how to use refresh token

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using Google Api to make changes in user calendar- synchronization with calendar in client app. I can't find any tutorial on how to and when use refresh token. Below is my test app to read from/write to google calendar. How can I check if access token expired, where should I do it and how to refresh token?

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CalendarQuickstart
{
    class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar };
        static string ApplicationName = "test";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream = new FileStream("NewFolder1/client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/test.json");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user1234",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;

            }

            // Create Google Calendar API service.
            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });


            // Define parameters of request.
            EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
            request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
            request.ShowDeleted = false;
            request.SingleEvents = true;
            request.MaxResults = 10;
            request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

            // List events.
            Events events = request.Execute();
            Console.WriteLine("Upcoming events:");
            if (events.Items != null && events.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
                {
                    string when = eventItem.Start.DateTime.ToString();
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(when))
                    {
                        when = eventItem.Start.Date;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", eventItem.Summary, when);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No upcoming events found.");
            }

            /////////////
            Event newEvent = new Event()
            {
                Summary = "Google I/O 2015",
                Description = "A chance to hear more about Google's developer products.",

                Start = new EventDateTime()
                {
                    DateTime = DateTime.Now,
                },
                End = new EventDateTime()
                {
                    DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
                },
            };

            String calendarId = "primary";
            EventsResource.InsertRequest requestInsertEvent = service.Events.Insert(newEvent, calendarId);
            Event createdEvent = requestInsertEvent.Execute();
            Console.WriteLine("Event created: {0}", createdEvent.Id);
            /////////////

            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to test if the access token is expired the client library is going to handle that for you.

However if for some reason you really want to you can send it to

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=1/fFBGRNJru1FQd44AzqT3Zg
```

It will return an error if its not valid.

Comment: So I don't need to do any refreshing?

Comment: no you don't the refresh tokens are stored using file datastore.   The client library has them and it will refresh the access token when it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

DaImTo is right, you don't need to worry about it the client library will do that for you.

A tutorial and more details are available here:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#acquiring--client-ids-and-secrets
including the [User Credential](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#user-credentials) section mentioning the following:

UserCredential and AuthorizationCodeFlow take care of automatically "refreshing" the token, which simply means getting a new access token. This is done using a long-lived refresh token, which you receive along with the access token if you use the access_type=offline parameter during the authorization code flow.